# Is there a way to trap a keyboard event in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to trap key downs in GWT, and I've tried both addKeyDownHandler and onBrowserEvent. The problem is that they work as long as the appropriate widget had the focus, but it stops working when something else has the focus. I could add the code to every single widget, but that seems crazy. I also tried forcing one single widget to always have the focus, but that causes other problems with things like TextBoxes (which need the focus for typing).

Is there just a simple, high-level way to trigger some code when a key is pressed in GWT, regardless of which widget has the focus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use either [`Event.addNativePreviewHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.html#addNativePreviewHandler%28com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.NativePreviewHandler%29), or a `KeyDownHandler` that you'd attach to `RootPanel.get()` (using [`addDomHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#addDomHandler%28H,%20com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.Type%29): `RootPanel.get().addDomHandler(myHandler, KeyDownEvent.getType())`), depending on whether you want to listen in the *capture* or *bubble* phase (the *capture* phase is emulated in IE).

Comment: Thanks! This gives the best results so far, but there still seems to be a case where it doesn't work. It seems like if I click on some widgets that descends from FocusPanel, it stops working. Here is my code, exactly:

Comment: RootPanel root = RootPanel.get();
root.clear();root.addDomHandler(new KeyDownHandler()
  {
   public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event)
   {
    if (getInterface() != null)
    {
     getInterface().handleKeyDown(event);
    }
   }
  }, KeyDownEvent.getType());

Comment: If you use the bubbling phase then yes you're dependent upon other event handlers down the chain stopping the propagation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the keyDownHandler to the body element like this and add the handler to that? All javascript events will bubble down unless you prevent it in a `function()`.

Example :

`RootPanel.getBodyElement()`

Then wrap into a class to make it a Widget and addDomHandler like described [here](http://lemnik.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/using-event-handlers-in-gwt-16/). Or if this proves not very straightforward, then simply write as javascript in the hosted page, or use native methods(GWT allows you to write javascript using native keyword).